# Regression with two related independent variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling

I have two independent variables from a survey, one of which is technically a subset of the other:

1. Asks participants the frequency of chocolate eaten in the past month
2. Asks participants whether they had eaten any one of 3 different chocolate brands in the past month.

(so the second IV would be already included in the first IV).

I am new stats, so forgive me if this is a dumb question: is it possible to include both of these IVs in my regression model with my outcome? If not, then could I possibly create an 'index' of frequency by creating a new IV  that links both variables together and groups frequency as high, medium, low?

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: What is your outcome?  What is the point of your model?  Do you have frequencies per month for each of the 3 brands, or are the latter just yes/no?

Comment: I have two outcomes: 1) Chocolate brand recall (participants asked to name up to 4 chocolate brands) and 2) Chocolate brand preference (participants shown a picture of each of the 3 chocolate brands and asked to rate their preference for the brand based on Likert scale). As for the IV variable for chocolate brand frequency, I just have the frequencies of yes/no to each of the 3 brands